# Bootable Windows Clone

Tags: backup

I am looking for a software that basically does whatever Clonezilla does, but while the OS is running?

I don't mind if it's paid, as long as, it is up to 50 GBP / USD / EUR for a single license.

I am looking for a backup software that in X intervals will do a bootable copy of my machine on a single file, which later will be uploaded to a cloud drive.

In case of failure, I can go to another computer, download the copy, get it into a USB and boot from it to recover my computer to the backup's state.

Comment: I can recommend one which is constantly mirroring your drive, but not at regular intervals. Important to know ids that your solution must support Volume Shadow Service for backing up open files.

Comment: If it fits the "In case of failure, I can go to another computer, download the copy, get it into a USB and boot from it to recover my computer to the backup's state.", I am happy.

Comment: So long as we are talking hard-disk failure here; if you trash your Windows files, delete the Registry or a bunch of DLLs, the mirroring will do that on the backup disk too. It makes an exact copy, in real-time. What do you think?

Comment: Hm... I would prefer versioning so in case this happens I could have an older copy to go to.

Comment: You could try this https://www.paragon-software.com/home/brh/ and this https://www.paragon-software.com/home/dc-professional/ I don't have Windows right now so I can't try it.

Comment: I am using Paragon right now for other tasks and really is not there. It's sometimes very difficult to get what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, I have used Acronis Backup for this case. You can view their article on [Disk Backup vs. Cloning](https://www.acronis.com/en-au/personal/true-image-features/imaging/) to get a better understanding. In their newer builds, they cite:

> No need to shut down Windows and restart using bootable media. Unlike
>   other disk cloning software, with Acronis True Image 2018 you can
>   create a clone directly on your USB external drive or local drive
>   while still using the computer.

The [standard version](https://www.acronis.com/en-au/personal/buy-backup/) has capabilities to perform the required, and it [$49.99AUD](http://aud.currencyrate.today/usd/49.99) - bargain!

**Note** that you can also use their cloud services to store backups.

Comment: I will test in the next few days and vote for your answer. Thanks

Comment: @Sonamor did it work for you? If it did you should accept this answer.